# Insert a custom post type on WordPress user login, is it possible?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, custom-post-type

I have a form to insert a custom post type in database. Only registered users can insert the CPT so, if on submit user is not logged in, a modal login form (based on standard WordPress login) is shown.
Is it possibile to submit the CPT data and save it in database on successfull login?  I tried wp_login hook but seems the callback function isn't called on login form submit...

Comment: Why not hide your form behind a is_user_logged_in() test?

Comment: Please add your wp_login hook code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask